# Laravel HasManyThrough deep relationship

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent, relation

I have a multi-tenant setup where a tenant `HasMany` workspaces and a workspace `BelongsToMany` students. How do I create a relationship from the tenant where I retrieve all the students from all workspaces within the tenant?

I've took a look at `hasManyThrough` but that does not solve the problem. Right now I have this function:

```php
public function getStudents()
{
    $this->workspaces()->get()->map(function ($workspace) {
        return $workspace->students;
    })->flatten()->unique();
}
```

But I'd like to do it in a relation instead of the above code. Any advice?

```php
Tenant :HasMany=> Workspace(tenant_id) :BelongsToMany=> Student(student_workspace table)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen this package
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Comment: is there an intermediary (pivot) table between "workspaces" and "students" table (something like "student_workspace") ? I assume that you should have that pivot table as well, cuz I think the any workspace could have multiple students and each student could have multiple workspaces. am I right ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it through `join` like:

```
public function students(){
    return Student::select('students.*')
        ->join('student_workspace', 'students.id', '=', 'student_workspace.student_id')
        ->join('workspaces', 'workspaces.id', '=', 'student_workspace.workspace_id')
        ->join('tenants', 'tenants.id', '=', 'workspaces.tenant_id')
        ->where('tenants.id', $this->id);
}
```

Or like any normal relation using this package: [hasManyDeep](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) through the following steps:

First:

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep
```

In your `Workspace` model file:

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class, 'student_workspace');
}
```

In your `Tenant` model file:

```
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

class Tenant extends Model
{

    use HasFactory, HasRelationships;

    public function students(){
        return $this->hasManyDeepFromRelations($this->workspaces(), (new Workspace)->students());
    }

}
```

Hope this would be helpful.